# url rewrite htaccess and php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite URL and for that I have got following code.

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?uname=$1
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?uname=$1
```

now when I write url like **www.mywebsite.com/username** it works fine and not giving any error.

Now how can I get this URL even when I write **www.mywebsite.com/index.php?uname=username** in hit go.

I want to change **www.mywebsite.com/index.php?uname=username** to **www.mywebsite.com/username** when I write **www.mywebsite.com/index.php?uname=username** in URL.

As rewrite work for prefix of WWW I want same way to change my URL to **www.mywebsite.com/username** even if user **write www.mywebsite.com/index.php?uname=username**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?uname=$1
```

It will check if the file or directory doesn't exist, and if it doesn't it will assume it's an username and rewrite the URL.

If you want to redirect from `index.php?uname=username` to `/username` then you could add this to the top of your `index.php`:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "uname") !== false)
{
    header("Location: /" . $_GET['uname']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replay. It doesn't give me page not found error when I go to www.mywebsite.com/username URL but its not converting from www.mywebsite.com/index.php?uname=username to www.mywebsite.com/username