# Rewrite url in htaccess php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to rewrite url as following.

This is url : http://www.xyzdomain.com/?page=9

i want it like this : http://www.xyzdomain.com/9

Comment: possible duplicate of [url rewrite htaccess and php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348472/url-rewrite-htaccess-and-php)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+\?page=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```